# Rewrite rule conditionally replace

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, duplicates

i´ve got the following Problem

i have a multilanguage page with following url pattern:

```
foo.bar/foo
foo.bar/en/foo
foo.bar/de/foo
foo.bar/ru/foo
```

and so on..

as my default language is english, i have a duplicate content problem because

```
foo.bar/foo
foo.bar/en/foo
```

have the same content

so i´m no .htaccess pro and i could solve it by make a rewrite condition for every single url like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.foo.bar$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/foo /en/foo [R=permanent,L]
```

but what i´m rather after is some generic solution expression sth like:

```
if((first part after "/") != ("en/$" || "de/$" || "ru/$") { 
    add "en/$"
}
```

so that `foo.bar` redirects to `foo.bar/en`

and `foo.bar/bla/blu/ble` redirects to `foo.bar/en/bla/blu/ble`

can someone help me out ?

**UPDATE:**

using

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?foo\.bar$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|de|ru)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /en/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```

and calling   http://www.foo.bar

infinitely redirects to :

```
http://www.foo.bar/en//app.php
```

so i guess its colliding with some rewriterule on the very bottom of the ifmodule 
that seems to strip out the frontcontroller (app.php), heres the code :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1] 

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$ 
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?foo\.bar$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/(en|de|ru)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /en/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: is there a way to include the host? i have many different sites on this document root and i need to only apply to "foo.bar"

Comment: yes sure that can be done too, see updated one. Also don't forget to make it 301 once you have tested it.

Comment: cool,, pretty straightforward, unfortunatly it does not seem to work for me, i made some update to my question, maybe you have an idea ?

Comment: ok try updated rule now. Also if that doesn't work then provide your complete .htaccess in question.

Comment: yeah it works :D ! but i needed to exclude the ressource url patterns for images stylesheets etc. and i changed `RewriteRule ^ /en/%{REQUEST_URI}` to `^(.*)$ /en/$1`

Comment: could you explain the difference of `!\s/(..` and `!^/(...`

Comment: Actually main difference was use of `%{THE_REQUEST}` instead of `%{REQUEST_URI}` and since `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1` I am matching it after `GET` and space.